# getting counts of the records in two joined queries

Tags: mysql

Having this query

```
    select ID, commonID, username, password, emailaddress 
from gc inner join rud on rud.commonID = gc.commonID 
limit 100
```

returning me duplicate records as the table **RUD** can have max of 3 records pertaining to the 1 record of the **GC** table.

like **GC** table has one entry and it can have 3 or 2 or 1 associated entry in the **RUD** table.

I want the query so that so i can get the count of the records from the **RUD** table associated to the **RC** table

like below:

```
entry1(3)
entry2(2)
entry3(1)
entry4(3)
entry5(3)
entry6(1)
entry7(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select gc.ID, count(*) as numberOfAssociated 
from gc inner join rud on rud.commonID = gc.commonID 
group by gc.ID
```